# Implementing Perl modules as plugins to a minimal core

Tags: perl, plugins, module

I'm writing a personal IRC bot for fun, though I'm pretty new to Perl. I want to implement a plugin system to allow the bot to be completely modular, and thus easily extended and modified. I would like to achieve the following:

- Minimal core that handles initialization and the IRC connection, and actual functionality is implemented by separate modules.
- Core does not need to be touched in order to add a new feature
- Dynamic Loading/Unloading of plugins at runtime, like irssi, WeeChat or an IRCd
- Modules should be self-contained and provide information about itself, as well as defining the necessary subroutines, vaguely similar to irssi/WeeChat plugins.

  - Variables like `name`, `description`, `author`, `version`, `cmdname` (if it implements a command)
  - Subroutines to handle any event it needs to like commands, specific phrases, intervals, etc

I think what I want is an API of sorts? What I currently have is a directory of **.pm** files, each of which define a few variables containing information about the module (module name, description, author, the command it responds to if applicable, etc) and specifically-named subroutines that the core will call depending on the event (someone issued a command, someone said a certain trigger phrase, some interval passed, etc).

A bit of research lead me to using [`Module::Pluggable`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Pluggable), and with it I have something close to what I want. To illustrate, I have the following:

```
MyBot/
|- Bot/
|  `- ModuleMan.pm
|- Modules/
|  |- Access.pm
|  |- NumGuess.pm
|  |- Quote.pm
|  `- ...
`- Bot.pl
```

**Bot.pl** is the core. It handles the basic stuff like connecting to IRC, reading configs, etc. Then I have a **Modules** directory which holds each of my modules (or "plugins" if you will). `Module::Pluggable` gives me an array containing each module's package name (see below). I have the following:

**Modules/Access.pm**

```
package Modules::Access;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $name = 'Access';
our $cmdname = 'access';
# other things like description, version, etc

sub handle_cmd {
    my ($self, $where, $who, %cmd) = @_;

    return unless $cmd{name} eq $cmdname;
    # do stuff
}
1;
```

**Bot/ModuleMan.pm**

```
package Bot::ModuleMan
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Pluggable
    sub_name    => 'getmodules',
    search_path => ['Modules'],
    require => 1;

sub new { return bless {}, shift; }
1;
```

**Bot.pl**

```
# ...
use Bot::ModuleMan;
my $mm = Bot::ModuleMan->new();
my @modules = $mm->getmodules();
# @modules holds ('Modules::Access', 'Modules::NumGuess', 'Modules::Quote', ...)
```

Then where I handle messages sent to the channel, I have the following:

```
my %command = parse_command($msg);
foreach my $module (@modules) {
    next unless $module->can('handle_cmd');
    $module->handle_cmd($channel, $nick, %command);
}
```

This works well enough, but as it stands I cannot access the variables defined in each module without resorting to symbolic references (which from what I've read seem to be ill-advised...), so for example, I can't move the command name check out of the module and into the core:

```
foreach my $module (@modules) {
    next unless $module->can('handle_cmd');

    # I want to be able to do something like this:
    next unless $module->cmdname eq $command{name} # nope...can't do that

    # But I'd have to do this...
    next unless ${$module . '::cmdname'} eq $command{name} # would also need no strict 'refs' in the block

    $module->handle_cmd($channel, $nick, %command);
}
```

On top of that, I wouldn't be able to access the other variables like the module's description for the same reason.

I'm pretty sure my design is flawed, and I don't know how to implement what I want to accomplish as I initially described. Do I need to implement classes somewhere? If so, how would I do that? Do I need to be using something along with `Module::Pluggable`, or something else entirely? Do I need to throw away what I have and start over? I've been utterly stuck and lost for a few days now trying to figure this out. What am I missing?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but in my days of Perl, when developing an API I used Moose.  It makes Perl a bit more OO and I know there are plugins to it like  MooseX::Object::Pluggable.  Forgive me if this is a bit outdated.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're trying to write this from scratch, but you might be able to borrow some ideas from [Bot::BasicBot::Pluggable](https://metacpan.org/release/Bot-BasicBot-Pluggable) - it uses Module::Pluggable for its extensibility.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see this. I'll skim the sources and see if I can't learn how he accomplished what I'm stuck on.